# ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'. i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Getting error, after I had updated the cli for implementing Angular4 carousel in Angular5. 
ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
    i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

```
**Below is the version details.** 

Angular CLI: 6.1.5    
Node: 8.9.4    
OS: win32 x64      
Angular: 5.2.1   
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms    
... http, language-service, platform-browser    
... platform-browser-dynamic, router    

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5    
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5     
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5     
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5     
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5     
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5      
@angular/cli                      6.1.5     
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5     
@schematics/angular               0.7.5      
@schematics/update                0.7.5      
rxjs                              5.5.6    
typescript                        2.5.3     
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular CLI version is 6.x. But the Angular Core library are 5.x. Seems like version mismatch. Try to upgrade Angular from 5 to 6 using https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for angular cli 6.x

Till it gets fixed you can use this workaround ,
you can add the app.module.ts to the files array in your tsconfig.app.json

```
 "files": [
      "../src/app/app.module.ts"
]
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10516

Answer (score 0):

The webpack should come as a part of @angular/cli.

```
npm remove webpack

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest.
```

This should fix your issue.
If this didn't, clear the whole node_modules folder
then

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

If @angular/cli install fails
Retry `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` again.